# Why do we use the dot operator (.) instead of the arrow operator (->) in arrays of structs as function parameters?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Consider`array` is an array of variables of type `structure` (struct).

When you pass an array of structs as a parameter to a function, you access it with the dot (`.`) operator:

`array[0].structField1`

Shouldn't it be accessed with the arrow (`->`) operator, since we're passing the address of the first element of the array, like:

`array[0]->structField1`

Comment: You would use the arrow operator if the array were an array of pointers to structs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array index operator `[]` contains an implicit pointer dereference.  So if `array` has either array-of-struct or pointer-to-struct type, then `array[0]` has struct type and not pointer type.

Comment: Specifically, you could use `(array+n)->member` or `array[n].member` but not `array[n]->member` since the levels of indirection are mismatched in the last one.